# Galleria, Adsense, and onLoad

Tags: php, jquery, custom-controls, gallery, adsense

(1) I am looking at image galleries and I would like to attach Adsense to my image gallery.. I found this Galleria image script and I'd like to add adsense to it. I have been looking around and asking questions but can't find anything.

(2) I'd like to load the images as the user scrolls down the page instead of all at once. I have no idea where to even get started with that.

Anyone done this or could do it?

http://galleria.io

Comment: There are plenty of solutions for [loading images on scroll](http://www.google.co.uk/#q=jquery%20load%20images%20on%20scroll), often referred to as [lazy loading](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

Comment: @Alex thanks for that! Anyone have ideas on adsense with galleria?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add to you list of images a transparent image (gif or png) and place your banner under the galleria controler/div. You can even have a custom image for the thumbnail so it doesn't appear you have an empty image in the list.

Having somehow the banner in the list directly will probably get your adsense account closed as at any display of your image/ad you'll request it from google and they don't allow excessive requests / page. But this would need a lot of tweaking w/galleria script.

Cheers